# Cassandra -What is really happens once Key-cache get filled

Tags: caching, cassandra, key-cache-size

Consider that I have configured 1 Mb of key-cache (Consider it can hold 13000 of keys ).

Then I wrote some records in a column family(say 20000).

Then read it at first (All keys sequentially in the same order used to write ), and keys are started to stored in key-cache.

When the read reached @ 13000 the key cache is filled completely.

What will happen to the key-cache when the next keys are read? (Which key is removed for the newly read key ?).

Key-Cache following FIFO or LIFO or Random out ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key cache uses `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` underneath and hence its eviction policy is LRU (least recently used).

https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/#Features

https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design#Beyond_LRU

Comment: Since only one read is performed on all the keys prescent in linked  Hashmap  the removal may become randome ? Or first in first out ?

Comment: In this particular case, the first inserted key will be evicted.

Comment: When all keys are stored as its hash , can we specifically say that 1 mb of keucache can store this much of keys ( as I said 13000)

Comment: The cache measures not a hash, but the size of a key itself and the size of a value. 

`size = key.unsharedHeapSize() + value.unsharedHeapSize();
`

Comment: Thanks for all the replies ... The value in the key cache context is the index in the stable for that key ?

Comment: In simple way , my question is ,the space consumed for one key in key-cache is same for all keys ?  Or it is based on the number of bytes in each keys

Comment: IWhat is the difference between setting key index sampling to 1  and key cache ..